# Setting source and data path in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, path, filenotfoundexception

I am little bit new in java. I have java source in workspace /src.I created a directory /data
in the same project.It means /project/src and /project/data are two directory. I would like to
put same directory rather than long absolute path. How would i do it?

```
BufferedReader buffR1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("../data/rural.train.txt")));
```

I did like this. But this is not working. I am finding file not found exception.

Comment: change this ../data/rural.train.txt to ../../data/rural.train.txt

Comment: this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a Run Configuration, go edit it and, under Arguments, set te Current directory to your data folder. Then you won't even need the `..` at the beginning of your path.

Comment: i could not follow you much. can you please elaborate it once?

Comment: Allright. Once you run a class in Eclipse, you can find a Run Configuration that was created for it. Click the little downward-facing triangle to the right of the green Play button in the toolbar, select "Run Configurations..."; on the left find your configuration under the Java Application node; now on the right you'll see the Arguments tab and there the Working directory configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

Two chioces:

1. make the path an argument passed in your programm
2. add the /data directory in your classpath, then you don't need specify the path anymore.